# How can I have read access to my Google Calendar tasks in a desktop application?

Tags: synchronization, google-calendar, tasks, thunderbird

Why don't I have access to my Google Calendar tasks using either Lighting for Thunderbird or Evolution?

I can sync calendars without any problems, but I do not even have read access to tasks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because **Google has not created any functionality in their Google Calendar APIs for doing anything with tasks**. Without an API for this, [applications would have to screen-scrape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445651/how-to-create-task-using-google-calendar-api/2448623#2448623), which is a pain and is inconvenient.

[Many developers want such an API](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=987), so such functionality will probably be added soon.

Until then, there's not much you can do. Sorry!